# Any other slash installations besides Slashdot

Tags: looking-for-a-script

I really want to use slashdot type functionality for a site and I think their source code is open, but I'm not sure how easy it is to use.  Is anyone else using it or know of any non-slashdot installations of it?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly it looks like a dead project to me. They do have a [page which lists /code sites they know about](http://slashcode.com/www.slashcode.com/sites.shtml) but it's broken. If you download the latest release file you'll see that the most recent [datestamp is 2006](http://sourceforge.net/projects/slashcode/files/), though someone does seem to have been fixing bugs as recently as last year.

Project on sourceforge is here http://sourceforge.net/projects/slashcode/

Basically anything slashcode/slashdot does can be done better in drupal or wordpress, it's a very 90's site in look, thinking and functionality.

Comment: Thanks.  hmmm drupal or wordpress isn't what I'm going for because what I really want is a site where users can submit stories.  I also like the voted upon comments.  Perhaps I should explore reddit

Comment: @andersonbd1 All of the things you describe are possible with Joomla, Drupal, twitter bootstrap or Wordpress. It may be better to view this kind of software as a platform modified by plugins, they're all maintained so more secure and more flexible for mobile and tablet than reddit or slashcode.